# Difficults with groupby() and both Bokeh figure()

Tags: pandas-groupby, bokeh

I don't know exactly where but I believe that I haven't assign the data to the figure, any help please to drag these data from the limbo back to the figure?

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_notebook, show
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.colors import RGB
from bokeh.sampledata.autompg2 import autompg2 as data


data = pd.read_csv('auto-mpg2.csv', thousands=',', index_col='class')
output_notebook()
print(data.dtypes)
dataHeads = data.head()

group =  data[100:150].groupby('class')
group1 = data[100:150].groupby('cty')
source = ColumnDataSource(group, group1)
#dataHeads
#yA = dataU.loc['a4']
#dataU.loc['malibu'].cty
p = figure(plot_height=500, plot_width=1200, x_range=group, title='City 
MPG vs Class MPG',
      x_axis_label='Class', y_axis_label='MPG')
p.vbar(x=index, top=index, width=0.9, color ='#35B778', source=source)

show(p)
```

Comment: Could you edit your question and explain what you want to plot? Right now you're referring to the column index in your ColumnDataSource but this column does not exist. (And it's empty because you are using a groupby object instead of a dictionary/dataframe)

Comment: Tony got the idea. i am new to python, came from java though not much time to sink all concepts as college does not allow you to do so, I find python very elegant.#

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_notebook, show
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.colors import RGB
from bokeh.sampledata.autompg2 import autompg2 as data

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
source = ColumnDataSource(df)
group = data[100:150].groupby('class')

p = figure(plot_height = 500, plot_width = 1200, x_range = group, title = 'City MPG vs Class MPG',
      x_axis_label = 'Class', y_axis_label = 'MPG')
p.vbar(x = 'class', top = 'cty', width = 0.9, color = '#35B778', source = source)

show(p)
```

[image]

Comment: Spot on Tony.
Thanks